# Запрос MYSQL используя 3 таблицы

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner

Имеется 3 таблицы. Хочу сделать выборку и подсчёт данных.
[image: Таблицқ]

Делаю выборку по **record** таблице в моем случае..

```
select *,count(items_id) as cnt from record inner join person on person.id = record.person_id inner join items on items.id=items_id
```

Вот хочу подсчитать в **record** сколько записей из **Person** имеет по **items**

**например: person:** 
[1,admin], [2,user]

**items:**
 [1,Login], [2,Reg]

**record:** 
 [1,1,1]....[n,2,1]

**Хочу такой результат:** 
подсчитать сколько раз admin записался как Login и Reg по отдельно с коль-во и user соответственно.
например admin сделал login 5 раз и reg 3 раза, а результат должен быть таков:
Я все не взял, просто конкретно привел пример, знаю в (select в моем случае) выдает все таблицы*
| person.Name | items.title | cnt **(count(x) as cnt)**
admin - Login - 5
admin - Reg - 3
user - Login - 9
user - Reg - 8

в таблице **record** всего 25 записей в моем случае. насчёт сортировки сам сделаю. Вот с выборкой проблемы.
 Благодарю заранее за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно сделать так

```
select 
  person.id as person_id, 
  person.Name as person_name, 
  items.id as item_id, 
  items.title as item_title, 
  count(items_id) as cnt 
from record 
inner join person on person.id = record.person_id 
inner join items on items.id=items_id
GROUP BY
person.id, 
person.Name, 
items.id, 
items.title
```